# Display IFrame IPython with custom auth headers

Tags: javascript, python, html, iframe, jupyter-lab

I am developing a JupyterLab Notebook and I need to embed a website for interaction with a dashboard from within the same notebook. This would be quite straight-forward using an IFrame.

However, to access this website, that I launch on my public server, JWT authentication is required so I need to send an additional header with the token. Which is the best way to do this? I am not familiar with HTML and JS so I am wondering where to start from.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Would need to do it using cookies. There's no way to set iframe request headers

Comment: Can I do it directly from JupyterLab before launching the IFrame? @charlietfl

Comment: I really know nothing about Jupyter Lab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I solved this issue by sending the token in the URL params using SSL traffic.